# Microsoft Teams for Organisations - deleting message in channel using curl

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I am trying to delete messages from a channel in Teams using curl.

I can post to a channel using a token and channel-id found when creating a Connector/web hook.

I can do this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"text": "Hello from curl!"}' https://<custom org>.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/<token>@<channel-id>/IncomingWebhook/<channel-id>
```

Now how can I delete a message again, using curl?

Note: I am on Teams for an Organisation

Comment: It is not possible to delete that message using Curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Beta you can use softDelete

Note: Microsoft have chosen not to use the DELETE method, but instead use a POST method

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/8f98f01d-1a73-401a-b9e9-9fd1e6f5e5ar/chats/19:22273db3497f4b32bue61f6e82be21c5@thread.tacv2/messages/1649864053377/softDelete
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-softdelete)